# 12.04 freezes due hybrid ssd?

Tags: freeze, ssd, drive, hybrid

Ubuntu 64bit installation freezes 3-5 times per day on my new desktop comupter. Only cold reboot is possible. I suppose the issues is due the SSD hybrid drive (Seagate Momentus 7200 FDE.2 ST950042) with 4 GB SSD Cache. But I don't find any log or hint what it might be except the following error:

```
dmesg | grep -i error
    [    1.066073]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d
    [    1.739775] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND     (20110623/psargs-359)
    [    1.739783] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff880211076000), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
    [    1.742334] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
    [    1.742343] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF] (Node ffff880211076000), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
    [    1.743891] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
[    1.743894] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF] (Node ffff880211076078), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
    [    1.744792] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
    [    1.744796] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed     [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF]    (Node ffff880211076078), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
    [    9.442399] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: You note that you are using 12.04 in the title.  Is this a new error since upgrading to 12.04?

Comment: I have the same problem on Xubuntu 12.04 and it is not problem of SSD. I had the problem when the system was not on SSD and now it is on it and the problem is still too. There is a problem with ACPI error which you can see in your log message. I have the same error and another users too. http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1167669 http://ubuntuforums.org/announce.html?t=1992970

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be either a bug with a new bios update on Asus motherboards and the Marvel controller.... 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43229

OR

A kernel bug that I have only just started getting since upgrading my bios (so perhaps the bios implemented something new, that has highlighted this bug in the kernel for me?)
http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?68651-ASPM-Linux-Kernel-Fix-To-Land-Finally-In-3-2-Series

I am leaning towards it being a bug in the kernel, but I am running a custom built kernel 3.4, and this should have been fixed in kernel 3.2?

The reason I am leaning towards it being the kernel is I have completely disabled the marvel controller and I still get the error. I have a drive on the marvel controller but it's just a static data drive, so perhaps that's why I'm not seeing any freezes as you are.

If you have an Asus motherboard and your ssd hybrid is connected to the marvell controller then try moving it off the the intel controller instead. If it's not then try updating your bios, and if that doesn't work then I guess it's pointing at a kernel bug for you also.